# 5V, 50 Ω input single pulse signal to an FPGA

Tags: fpga, signal, zener, input, 5v

I have a 5 V, 50 Ω input single pulse signal (<1 ms pulse width) going into Trenz TE0711 (operating @3.3 V and 50 MHz clock). Since the input signal is too high of a voltage, I am trying to find a way to reduce the voltage and keep jitter low (<1 ns). I also want it to be dummy proof where if someone puts in a high-voltage signal or an AC signal it doesn't fry the FPGA. I am not familiar with analog electronics, so I apologize if this is a simple question.

Currently, I am thinking of having a 3 V zener diode to act as a regulator and use a current limiting resistor (250 Ω) in front. However, I am not familiar with other components that may be out there that could meet my needs. I am concerned that zener diodes may have high jitter, but I just don't know. I am also worried if the 250 Ω resistor will cause a mismatch with the 50 Ω input signal and cause reflections.

Lastly, what would be the best way to test this? Could I use a delay/pulse generator and generate a 5 V, 50 Ω single shot pulse and just connect it directly onto my circuit that is on a breadboard and hook up an oscilloscope? Or, are there other ways to ensure proper and precise measurements?

Comment: What are the rise and fall times of the input signal? You need this information to determine if you will have an issue with reflections.

Comment: Also consider a buffer or inverter front-end to the FPGA pin.  You want the edge to be clean and fast regardless of whatever the user inputs.  Perhaps one with hysteresis also - might "take care of" minor line noise.

Comment: @ThePhoton The rise and fall times of the input signal vary depending on what device is used. It can be <750ps or 2-3ns. Also, the pulse width is <1ms.

Comment: @rdtsc Would a level shifter from 5V to 3V for this instead of a zener be more appropriate for this problem?

Comment: From where does the 5V signal come from, and does it have 50 ohm source impedance? If so, after 50 ohm termination, the pulse amplitude is 2.5V.

Comment: @Justme It comes from a delay/pulse generator like a DG535.

Comment: Eh, if you have an instrument with controllable output parameters, why not simply adjust the output to lower voltage, instead of adding circutry? And yes the generator has 50 ohm output. So, why not set the generaror to output a 3.3V pulse into 50 ohm, instead of setting it to output a 5V pulse?

Comment: Are you clocking the signal into a register? Be aware that you are likely not synchronous with an internal clock and you may want a glitch proof bit of logic depending on what you want to do with the signal.

Comment: @johnnymopo What do you mean by a glitch proof bit of logic?

Comment: @trident_ If you are clocking an external asynchronous signal, there is the potential for the rising edge ( what is the slew rate ) to not necessarily be 1 one (is it ringing slightly?).  What I would typically do for a general async signal is to do what is similar to what you would find if you look up "debounce" for switches, however many of these inputs don't need that extreme of a case.  you can run the signal into a shift register and use the OR of the register.  You can also have a following register of the OR and use the OR and the negate of it's follower as a rising-edge detector.

Comment: @trident_, do you (a) understand metastability and (b) know techniques for giving your circuit immunity to it from inputs? More importantly and first though, (c) why does you want such low jitter on this 1ms signal, can you explain what the application is. Edit (c) into your question. You may very well not need such tight jitter constraints of 1/1,000,000 of pulse width. Let's be very sure of the question before churning out answers. Info, in plenty of detail, please.

Comment: @johnnymopo Oh yes, I have that set up on the FPGA side.

Comment: @TonyM Yes, metastability is the potential for digital electronics to enter a state where it won't be a 1 or 0. Happens due to timing violations (set up and hold times) or voltage thresholds. I am not familiar with techniques to give circuit immunity to it. All I can state is that I need a jitter of less than 1 ns due to a spec. But, the jitter requirement isn't a top priority at the moment after some discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 5 V signal that must go into a 50R termination resistance. You can use the below circuit. This reduces the 5 V to approx. 2.7 V, well above the 2.0 V min. for an LVTTL input HIGH and above the 2.3 V min (70% of 3.3 V) for LVCMOS.

Configure your FPGA input pin to be a Schmitt trigger, if it can. That will use an even lower logic HIGH threshold voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f68SDz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 protects the FPGA input pin from overvoltages by clamping the input to 0.3 V above the supply rail. D2 protects it against undervoltages by clamping it to 0.3 V below GND. Current limit resistor R3 reduces the overvoltage/undervoltage current to a safe level. You can modify the R3 value to suit the voltages it could be subject to. R2 will already load transients and dissipate them so it's continuous overvoltages that are the concern. When driven by a cable, it's a good idea.

A propagation delay is produced by R3, the capacitance of D1, D2 and the FPGA input pin, along with the tracking impedance. If this threatens your low jitter requirement, you can go without R3, D1 and D2.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Built on breadboard and connected it to a DG535 and a Tektronix scope (3.25GS/s sample rate). I took a delay measurement between the input and output and looked at the variance (jitter) and got ~600 ps. I am wondering if my jitter measurement is accurate as I was using a standard breadboard and am worried that I may have noise/interference through the contacts and capacitance within the breadboard. Would it be better to make the jitter measurement by implementing the above circuit on a prototype PCB board? I ask this as this a subcircuit within an entire system that must have a jitter <1 ns.

Comment: @trident_, I think it's asking too much to get such a tight jitter requirement out of a breadboard circuit, particularly over time and if you're planning to make more. A PCB with decent tracking impedances and a ground plane will certainly improve things but that also depends on the rest of the system circuit you have.

Comment: Alright, I think I should also get a hold of a better oscilloscope with higher resolution since the resolution of the current scope is ~300 ps. So, the jitter variance is really a variance of 2 samples, which is probably not ideal by any means.

Comment: I did some AC tests and put a 5V AC signal in and got -0.7 V across the FPGA on the -V part of the AC signal. The concern I have is the FPGa datasheet lists the minimum voltage as being -0.4V which exceeds the minimum spec on the datasheet. Also, if I put in a 9 V AC signal, I end up with nearly 5 V across the FPGA, which exceeds the maximum voltage of the FPGA datasheet. Is a zener circuit worth doing instead?

Comment: For -0.7 V, you've used the wrong diodes - use BAT54/BAT81. They have a 0.3 V drop at that current, which would keep the FPGA pin at -0.3 V. So replace those first. For the 5 V, increase the R3 value. As a jump, try 10K, you'll get a low voltage (with the right diodes) but increased phase shift i.e. delay. Try 2K2, work your way along resistor values. Try a 10K linear pot' and experiment if you've got one. The current that can be clamped depends on the load on the 3V3 regulator. Zener's not the first resort, they bring their own problems but often get seen just as 'magic voltage drops'.

Comment: Figured out the diode stuff and got it working, when I do a negative voltage. I get a negative current through R3 which makes sense, but I am wondering if I need to worry about damage to the FPGA.

Comment: @Trident_, not if they're inside the maximum voltage range you don't. Are they?

Comment: Now they are! Thank you!

Comment: Also, no need to answer, just curious what would be some of the problems of a Zener in this situation?

Comment: Glad it works. Zeners have a set of characteristics, notably inaccurate breakdown (switch-on) voltage, min conduction current to get rated Vbreakdown, leakage current near breakdown. As said, they get seen as 'magic voltage drops' that cut in/out of circuit perfectly at a voltage. I've done/do protected input stages a lot and never use Zeners, always been a better (simpler, more accurate) way. They have their place, like any component. Here, overvoltage current goes into the rail so rail load must be enough to draw that extra current when rail regulator sees rail voltage rise and backs off.